# How to sort whole line with another line of input in JAVA?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

i got a problem to share with you guys hoping for a better answer with the explanation,

> Input
>
> 2 5
>
> 5 1
>
> 2 1
>
> 3 1
>
> 1 1
>
> 4 1

Here '5' in the first line is number of test cases .
Suppose if i take second line and third line as example and i would like to swap the second line with the third line is it possible ? i know how to swap single number with another with the help of selection sort , bubble sort etc ... but no idea how to swap whole thing..

what i mean by whole thing is ...

3 1

1 1

```
 for (int i = 0 ;i< array.length; i++){
  int min = i;

  for (int j = i+2; j<array.length; j++){
    if (array[j] < array[min]){
      min = j;
    }
  }
  char temp = array[min];
  array[min] = array[i][j];
  array[i][j] =  temp;
```

what kind of update i have to do in my sorting code to swap the whole thing?

Comment: Could you give a little more detail on what you're sorting? Is it the sum of the arrays that are being compared, the first digit, etc?

Comment: You could either save the lines as strings and sort them (extracting the number you are looking for might degrade performance) or, my prefered solution, create a class that represents those lines, with an appropriate comperator for the sorting. Not knowing what you really want to accomplish, it's difficult to give a good answer to the question in its current state.

Comment: A simple bubble sort would do the trick. I can give you a sample code to sort the whole thing, but currently I don't really understand what are you trying to achieve. I have to agree with @ErichKitzmueller

Comment: @djharten in think i made it clear with the examples . Example : i want to swap row 3 with row 2 (in row 2 we have [3 1] and in row 3 we have [1 1] i just wanna swap it .  )

Answer (score 1):

From the line `array[min] = array[i][j];` I think you need to understand how arrays work first. You cannot assign an element ( Value ) to an array.

Assuming you have the input in a 2d array as below:

```
array = {
          {5, 1},
          {2, 1},
          {3, 1},
          {1, 1},
          {4, 1}
        }
```

You could sort them using built in sort of [`Arrays`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) in Java with a simple comparator like:

```
Arrays.sort( array, new Comparator<int[]>() {
   @Override
   public int compare( int[] a, int [] b ) {
      return a[0] - b[0]; //you compare only first elements
   }
});
```

If you see above, it compares the first elements only and the array will be sorted based on first value in each element.

`Arrays.sort()` uses a version of quick sort and hence should be more efficient than selection or bubble sort.

Comment: Shorter Java8 version: `Comparator.comparingInt(array -> array[0])`.

Comment: @SomeDude  i didnt understand the use of comparator  !Can you review your code is there any problem with the code ?